# How to substitute values in a pd.Series for their ratio of occurrence?

Tags: python, pandas

ie.

```
data = pd.Series(['a','b','b','c','c','c','d','d','d','d'])

expected_output(data) == pd.Series([.1,.2,.2,.3,.3,.3,.4,.4,.4,.4]) # all True
```

(tried a few variations of *group_by().count()* but no success)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the counts and then map each element of the series to its count:

```
counts = data.value_counts(normalize=True)
result = data.apply(lambda x: counts[x])
```

Comment: Use `data.map(data.value_counts(normalize=1))` over apply, will be *much* faster on larger datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try

```
 data.value_counts(normalize=True)#Based on the question initially asked.
```

With your comments

```
data=pd.Series(['a','b','b','c','c','c','d','d','d','d'])
ratio=data.map(data.value_counts(normalize=True).to_dict())
```

Comment: that gives me a Series with the unique values and their corresponding ratio

Comment: @L. B. answered based on what I first saw before you edited question. See my edits for aternative approach to your edited question